# fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

Tags: git

При создании команды `git add` для файла .txt появляется это:

```sh
git add first-file.txt
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

с чем это связано? Работаю в git bash.

Comment: Переведите ошибку, и ее суть вам откроется

Comment: а как в git bash перейти на рабочий стол?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)